# Vort or an engagement party?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, engagement-shidduch

The word *vort* (which is yiddish) has been translated by [Frumspeak](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Frumspeak-The-First-Dictionary-Yeshivish/dp/1568216149) to mean:

1) *Any material that imparts beneficial knowledge: Lesson.*

2) *A concisely expressed precept: Moral.*

Wikipedia translates the word [*vort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement_party) and gives it a whole new meaning:

*An engagement party is a party held to celebrate a couple's recent engagement and to help future wedding guests to get to know one another. Traditionally, the bride's parents host the engagement party, but many modern couples host their own celebration.*

How did the word *vort* come to mean ***an engagement party***?

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally the Chossen is expected to give over a "vort" ie. Torah idea in order to show his future bride and in laws that he is learned. The occasion was named after the vort, and the name stuck even as the practice of actually saying the vort fell out of use.

Comment: Thus, "vort" is a synecdoche when used to refer to an engagement party.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Fred for a new vocabulary word.

Answer (score 3):

A Vort is held when two sides gave each other their "vort" that they will marry each other.

Comment: You missed the whole point of my question.

Comment: Unfortunately many of your questions are asked in a way that I do not see the point. Perhaps you should work on explaining your point better, and thus you will get upvotes instead of downvotes, and answers that are more to the point.

Comment: +1. Although I've heard that [Nafkamina's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55323) is correct, [this comment from the Avodah archives](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol26/v26n088.shtml#02) supports your answer. It would be nice to find out which is the real origin of this use of "*vort*."